# not able to insert object to JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
"myfield": {
        "answers": {
            "Key1": "value1",
            "Key2": "value2"
        }
    }


var Obj2={"key3":"value3"}
```

I am struggling for putting the Obj2 into **myfield** object using javascript

**Expected Result:**

```
"myfield": {
        "answers": {
            "Key1": "value1",
            "Key2": "value2",
            "Key3": "value3"
        }
    }
```

Comment: *How* are you struggling? *What have you tried?*

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Object.assign()` to get desired result.

```js
var obj1 = {
  "myfield": {
    "answers": {
      "Key1": "value1",
      "Key2": "value2"
    }
  }
}
var obj2 = {
  "key3": "value3"
}

Object.assign(obj1.myfield.answers, obj2);
console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `for in`

```js
var data = {
  "myfield": {
    "answers": {
      "Key1": "value1",
      "Key2": "value2"
    }
  }
}
var obj2 = {
  "key3": "value3"
}

for(k in obj2){
data["myfield"]["answers"][k] = obj2[k]
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json='{'+
        '"answers": {'+
            '"Key1": "value1",'+
            '"Key2": "value2"'+
       ' }'+
    '}';
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
var obj=JSON.parse(json);
obj.answers.key3="value3";
console.log('"myfield":'+JSON.stringify(obj));
```